# Neo4j Cypher: Match multiple property values in array

Tags: neo4j

This query is working to match a single property value `'DOWNLOAD'` for `content` in an array:

```
MATCH (profile:Profile)
MATCH (profile)-[:LINK]->(l)
WHERE ANY(content IN l.content WHERE content = 'DOWNLOAD')
RETURN DISTINCT profile
```

But I get an error with multiple property values `'DOWNLOAD'` and `'RECENT'` for `content` and `type` when including `AND` inside `WHERE ANY()`:

```
MATCH (profile:Profile)
MATCH (profile)-[:LINK]->(l)
WHERE ANY(content IN l.content WHERE content = 'DOWNLOAD' 
AND type IN l.type WHERE type = 'RECENT')
RETURN DISTINCT profile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [To check if an element exists in a list, you can use the IN operator](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/where/#where-in-operator):

```
MATCH 
  (profile:Profile)
MATCH 
  (profile)-[:LINK]->(l)
WHERE 
  'DOWNLOAD' IN l.content AND
  'RECENT'   IN l.type
RETURN 
  DISTINCT profile
```